# Excel Replace all Values between Delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these many rows in excel which i:

```
2584;2591;3529
2817;2852
520;3302;3612;4342;3668
520;330;2520
```

I want to replace all numbers by NA

```
NA;NA;NA
NA;NA
NA;NA;NA;NA;NA
NA;NA;NA
```

Whats the most simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Microsoft365's dynamic arrays and `FILTERXML()` you could try the below:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",,IF(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),"NA"))
```

Or, a bit more universal could be:

```
=REPT("NA;",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","")))&"NA"
```

Comment: Wicked! Thanks, perfect solution!